# Azure Proxy Timing Out

Tags: azure-functions, azure-function-app-proxy

I have a WebAPI which I have set up a function proxy to.

Some requests on the webAPI can take a few minutes to complete.

Going direct to the WebApi works fine but when I go through the proxy it is always timing out at 1 minute.

Is there anyway to extend this?
Thanks

Comment: You can change the function timeouts here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functiontimeout

Answer (score 2):

We have verified this is a bug in Functions V2 host. opened github issue here for tracking: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3730

Comment: Thank you.  Will wait for fix and test again.

Answer (score 0):

Azure function proxies should obey the `host.json` file for timeouts as per: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functiontimeout

```
{
    "functionTimeout": "00:05:00"
}
```

If this doesn't work for you, please submit feedback on the link at the bottom of the page.